# Where should I put all these uploaded files?

Tags: php, mongodb, upload, media

I'm building a webapp that as a small subset of one of the features allows images to be uploaded. I'm running a lamp stack, with Mongo instead of MySql.

I use a javascript uploader with a php backend to upload the files. The whole framework is under version control though, so I don't want to dump these files anywhere inside my framework, as it would get messy with the version control, and sub-optimal when I eventually migrate the media over to a CDN.

So, my question is - On a VPS, where should I drop these images for now? In some folder external to my framework? In my DB as bson? I've heard Mongo does a decent job handling binary data...

And, as a follow up, if I'm eventually planning on moving the content over to a CDN, how would you recommend structuring my schema for now?

My current plan would be something like the following:

1. All uploads are named with a unique
   ID and dropped in an external
   folder, defined by a globally
   accessible variable of sorts.
2. A reference to each images' name is
   stored in the db.

Is there anything obviously stupid about going about it that way, possibly causing me a scaling headache later?

Here's a summarized specific question, just so this is a little more of an SO friendly question:

**Given a Linux, Apache, Mongo, PHP Framework on a VPS, what is the best way to store uploaded images while keeping scalability and speed as the 2 most important factors in deciding on the solution?**

Comment: Most version controls allow you to ignore files in a folder.

Comment: certainly, but I've always thought putting non-essential and user generated content inside of a framework pretty bad practice. I suppose I could be wrong, but even if I were, it would make migration to a CDN or scaling the site a giant hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your plan is moving to CDN, the answer couldn't be more easy: create a subdomain on your VPS, and drop your images there, and you will have decent CDN simulation as well as reliable file storage.

Comment: Definitely the direction I'm going. Not sure if there's any precedent for storing media, hopefully this is about the closest there is?

Comment: @Jesse not sure I catch what you mean but that's very common way to store media. Just open this very page source and search for sstatic.com domain

Answer (score 1):

I do agree that you should never put user uploaded content inside your webapp for many number of reasons but then one of the problem is how to show img tag in HTML which takes src attribute relative to webapp.

An easy workaround can be: Suppose create a folder /usr/ImagesUPloadByUser on your unix box and drop all images there. and then create a link ( linux link) in your webapp which points to correct directory. Now the images are not residing in ur webapp and you also have easy access .